# Dissable low battery pop-up

Tags: 20.04, battery, notification

I am using ubuntu 20.4 and my laptop has a prob with the battery
A notification keeps popping up
[this is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7vRp.png)
Can someone help me to disable this?

Comment: Your screenshot is empty.

Comment: Sorry, now it should be fine

Answer (score 0):

This can be done rather quickly with `dconf-editor`:

1. Open `dconf-editor`
2. Click through to `org` ⇢ `gnome` ⇢ `settings-daemon` ⇢ `plugins` ⇢ `power`
3. Change the values of `percentage-critical` and `percentage-action` to something like 1%
4. Change use-time-for-policy to `false`
5. Close the editor

Hope this helps